# Haskell Rotate String with exeptions

Tags: string, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to shift a character by one to the right and that the last character will always be first, and that it would return a string.

For example: `shiftString "abcd" = "dabc"` but the compiler doesn't agree with me, can anybody help me fix this?

```
shiftString :: String -> String
shiftString x = take (length x) $ iterate rot1 x
        where rot1 = drop 1 x ++ take 1 x
```

Also, I want to check after this on two Strings and returns True if one of them is a result of applying shiftString one or more times, how can I use this to do that? as in:

```
isShifted :: String -> String -> Bool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `String` in Haskell is just a list of `Char`s - so you can do this using simple pattern-matching:

```hs
shiftString' :: String -> String
shiftString' (firstChar:restChars) = restChars ++ [firstChar]
shiftString' [] = []
```

now if you try this it'll do the opposite of what you want - but there is a trick: we reverse the string twice:

```hs
shiftString :: String -> String
shiftString = reverse . shiftString' . reverse
```

that should do the trick

---

fix yours:

I think you only need the `rot1` (it does the same as my `shiftString'`) together with the reverse trick from above

Or - to fix yours more:

I guess you tried with the iterate to `rot1` more times and then drop the rest - that works too:

```hs
shiftS cs = head $ drop (length cs - 1) $ iterate rot1 cs

rot1 cs = drop 1 cs ++ take 1 cs
```

note that `iterate` gives you a list of strings (with more and more rotations) - I drop the first `n-1` (where `n` = length of the input) which gives me a list again (one type-error on your version) and take the head of that because I only want the first `String` in this list.

---

for your `isShifted` you can reuse the `iterate` with `rot1` (no need to care about order) - this time take `length cs` from this and then check if your other input is an element of this list:

```hs
isShifted cs cs' = cs `elem` take (length cs) (iterate rot1 cs')
```

Example:

```hs
Prelude> isShifted "abcd" "cdab"                                           
True                                                                       
Prelude> isShifted "abdc" "cdab"                                           
False
```

note that you cannot just use `iterate rot1 cs'` without the take - think about it and then try what happens ;) (hint: it'll work when your inputs *are* shifted - but you'll get into trouble if they are not - why?)

Comment: how can you call this function in order to check if two string are a result of "shiftString"?

Comment: I updated this too - I like to do this in steps ;) - I hope I don't spoil too much for you - is this homework?

Comment: used to be but I got it wrong and I'm trying to learn from my mistakes(:

Comment: `head (drop n foo)` is more idiomatically written `foo !! n`.

Comment: yes thanks! There is probably a lot more I could rewrite - my idea was to keep it as close to the original code as I thought reasonable

Answer (score 0):

```
-- shiftString "abcd"   == "dabc"
-- shiftString "hello"  == "ohell"
-- shiftString "orange" == "eorang"

shiftString :: [a] -> [a]
shiftString lst = [ head (reverse lst)] ++ (init lst)


-- Test Cases
-- isShifted "abcdefg" "gabcdef"   == True
-- isShifted "hello" "ohell"       == True
-- isShifted "orange" "eorange"    == False



isShifted :: String -> String -> Bool
isShifted str1 str2                  
        | shiftString str1  == str2 = True
        | otherwise             = False
```